# convert array of strings into array of ints

Tags: javascript

I collect the current value of a range slider every 1 second and store those values in an array. The value are saved as `["34", "23", "21"]`. I need them to save as ints like `[6, 4, 3, 2]` before I can use them as data in my `charts.js` canvas. Haven't been able to find a clear answer!

Comment: While storing convert it into int using `parseInt()` function and store.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g11wm6LL/1/

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can one-line it using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var arr = ["34", "23", "21"];
arr.map(Number);
>>> [34, 23, 21]
```

Comment: I didn't know you can map to a type. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can use javscript function parseInt() to acheive it

for example:-

```
var x=["1","2","3","4"]
x.forEach(function(item){
 console.log(parseInt(x,10));
});
```

it will console all numeric values

Comment: always use parseInt with radix spcified `parseInt(x,10)` as some old browsers may have unexpected behavior

Comment: @Gaafar i agree with you,providing radix would be a plus point as exceptional handling point of view.